# class based generic views extra context

Tags: django

Before class based views there was an extra_context keyword that can be passed in urlsconf.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views/#adding-extra-context

Now with class based generic views, if we want to do the same we have to subclass the generic view
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#adding-extra-context

If we want something simple, and we are using the generic CreateView and UpdateView. This approach will force to subclass for something that before was trivial. Even more, we have to break the DRY principle, doing it twice.

Why is it like this?
Is there any reason why we can not pass the extra context directly to the template?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After too much thoughts, the only answer is NO, that functionality was removed.

And the documentation does not mention the "Removed feature" and there is no explanation why it was like this.

But for making my life easier I took the advice from @aidan and modified a little bit

```
class ExtraContext(object):
    extra_context = {}

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExtraContext, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(self.extra_context)
        return context

class ExtraListView(ExtraContext, ListView):
    pass

class ExtraDetailView(ExtraContext, DetailView):
    pass

class ExtraUpdateView(ExtraContext, UpdateView):
    pass

class ExtraCreateView(ExtraContext, CreateView):
    pass 

class ExtraDeleteView(ExtraContext, DeleteView):
    pass

class ExtraCloneView(ExtraUpdateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return ExtraCreateView.as_view(model=self.model,
                              template_name=self.template_name,
                              extra_context=self.extra_context)(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now I have semi-generic views that I can use directly in the URLSconf and pass extra_context dict to the as_view() call

```
url(r'^camera/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 
    views.ExtraDetailView.as_view(model=models.Camera,
                               extra_context={'action_type': 'detail', 'mod_name' : 'camera'},
                               template_name='cameras/camera_detail.html'), 
    name='camera_detail'),
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, I made almost all of my project around class-based generic views on urls, and without this I would had to change everything

Comment: 2.0 brought back `extra_context` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#contextmixin

Answer (score 15):

I guess it's not quite so simple, but it's still only 5 lines of code -

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['my_additional_context'] = my_object
        return context
```

If you really want that functionality with class based views, then perhaps you could extend the class to add it -

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView)
    additional_context = {}
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context.append(self.additional_context)
        return context
```

Then use it in your url_conf -

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #....
    (r'^my_url/$', MyCreateView.as_view(additional_context={'my_addional_context': my_object})),
)
```

You could write your own CreateView, DetailView, ListView etc and import them into every project you do.

Comment: The problem is not how to do it subclassing the generic views, the problems is that this functionality was removed.

Comment: yeah, I guess. I don't really have an answer to your question. I don't know why it was removed.

Comment: this will work, but there is an old Django rule "Don't pass anything to url views in the url file!" this will make it slower! resource from two scoops of django( a book)

Answer (score 11):

Reading the above answers, it seemed that this approach, while solving the problem, was essentially a hack to bring back old functionality. A little googling brought up the [generic class-based views page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context), which contains a section titled "[adding extra context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)." Just to summarize here, the solution is simply to implement your own version of `get_context_data()` which would include the variables you want to pass to the templates:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from books.models import Publisher, Book

class PublisherDetail(DetailView):

    model = Publisher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```

The biggest benefit here is that you are not required to "hack" `urls.py` to include all sorts of context arguments, you can take advantage of all the functionality provided by class-based views while still providing custom-defined context content.

Comment: @fariza - The code is the same, the difference is the approach. The accepted answer uses the above code to pass data to `as_view` (if I'm understanding it correctly). This suggests to use the code to pass the arguments to the template directly, without needing to modify anything in `urls.py`.

Comment: the original question was about removed functionality and how to bring it back. That functionality implied generic views that accepted extra context from the urls.py

Answer (score 1):

Just use `extra_context`, this was added back in 2017 (https://github.com/django/django/pull/8671)

Answer (score 0):

With full credit to mogga's comment to the accepted answer::

> 2.0 brought back extra_context docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/… – mogga

So the way to get it is to upgrade to 2.X if you're not on it already.